# Console List View A-to-Z

Tags: service-cloud-console, console

Does anyone know the rules that determine if the A-to-Z is displayed on the Service Cloud Console views (specifically Cases but i assume they are all the same)?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

We have since determined that it appears when you sort the list on a column that contains text.  It dissapears if  the colum is a number.

...makes a lot sense really!